# Magento plugins

Tags: magento, plugins

I am trying to install 2 plugins for magento: free-testimonial and MW_EasyTestimonial. 
During installation I found that 2 plugins using the same names:

file app\code\community\Magebuzz\Testimonial\etc\config.xml:

```
<default>
    <testimonial>
        <general_option>
            <show_link_testimonial>1</show_link_testimonial>
            <enable_sidebar>1</enable_sidebar>
            <enable_testimonial_paging>1</enable_testimonial_paging>
            <divide_page>9, 15, 30, 'all'</divide_page>
            <max_testimonials_sidebar>3</max_testimonials_sidebar>
            <testimonial_sidebar_slider>0</testimonial_sidebar_slider>
        </general_option>
        <testimonial_options>
            <testimonial_captcha_enabled>1</testimonial_captcha_enabled>
            <allow_customers_write_testimonial >1</allow_customers_write_testimonial >
            <allow_guest_write_testimonial>0</allow_guest_write_testimonial>
            <approve_testimonial>1</approve_testimonial>
            <thank_message><![CDATA[Your testimonial was successfully posted and waiting for approval.]]></thank_message>
        </testimonial_options>
        <email_configuration>
            <send_email_after_post_testimonial>0</send_email_after_post_testimonial>
            <send_email_after_approve_testimonial>0</send_email_after_approve_testimonial>
            <select_template_post>testimonial_email_configuration_select_template_post</select_template_post>
            <select_template_approve>testimonial_email_configuration_select_template_approve</select_template_approve>
        </email_configuration>
    </testimonial>
</default>
<modules>
    <Magebuzz_Testimonial>
        <version>0.1.4</version>
    </Magebuzz_Testimonial>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <testimonial>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magebuzz_Testimonial</module>
                <frontName>testimonial</frontName>
            </args>
        </testimonial>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <testimonial>
                <file>testimonial.xml</file>
            </testimonial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <testimonial>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magebuzz_Testimonial</module>
                <frontName>testimonial</frontName>
            </args>
        </testimonial>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <testimonial>
                <file>testimonial.xml</file>
            </testimonial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>   
<global>
    <models>
        <testimonial>
            <class>Magebuzz_Testimonial_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>testimonial_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </testimonial>
        <testimonial_mysql4>
            <class>Magebuzz_Testimonial_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <testimonial>
                    <table>simple_testimonial</table>
                </testimonial>
            </entities>
        </testimonial_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <testimonial_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Magebuzz_Testimonial</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </testimonial_setup>
        <testimonial_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </testimonial_write>
        <testimonial_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </testimonial_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <testimonial>
            <class>Magebuzz_Testimonial_Block</class>
        </testimonial>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <testimonial>
            <class>Magebuzz_Testimonial_Helper</class>
        </testimonial>
    </helpers>
    <template>
        <email>
            <testimonial_email_configuration_select_template_post translate="label" module="testimonial">
                <label>Custom Email Template After Post Testimonial</label>
                <file>email_template_after_post_testimonial.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </testimonial_email_configuration_select_template_post >
            <testimonial_email_configuration_select_template_approve translate="label" module="testimonial">
                <label>Custom Email Template After Approve Testimonial</label>
                <file>email_template_after_approve_testimonial.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </testimonial_email_configuration_select_template_approve >
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

file app\code\local\Hm\Testimonial\etc\config.xml:

```
<modules>
    <Hm_Testimonial>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </Hm_Testimonial>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <testimonial>/testimonial/</testimonial>
    </secure_url>
    <routers>
        <testimonial>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Hm_Testimonial</module>
                <frontName>testimonial</frontName>
            </args>
        </testimonial>
    </routers>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <testimonial>
                <file>testimonial.xml</file>
            </testimonial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
<translate>
    <modules>
    <Hm_Testimonial>
        <files>
        <default>Hm_Testimonial.csv</default>
        </files>
    </Hm_Testimonial>
    </modules>
</translate>    
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
    <testimonial>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
            <module>Hm_Testimonial</module>
            <frontName>testimonial</frontName>
        </args>
    </testimonial>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
        <Hm_Testimonial>
            <files>
            <default>Hm_Testimonial.csv</default>
            </files>
        </Hm_Testimonial>
        </modules>
    </translate>    
    <menu>
        <testimonial module="testimonial">
        <title>Testimonials</title>
        <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
        <children>
            <items module="testimonial">
            <title>Manage Testimonials</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>testimonial/adminhtml_testimonial</action>
            </items>    
             <configurations module="testimonial">
            <title>Configuration</title>
            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/hm_testimonial</action>
            </configurations>       
        </children>
        </testimonial>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <Hm_Testimonial>
                        <title>Testimonial Module</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <items module="testimonial" translate="title">
                                <title>Manage Product</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </items>                                
                        <configurations module="testimonial" translate="title">
                                <title>Configurations</title>
                                <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        </configurations>
                    </Hm_Testimonial>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <hm_testimonial>
                                        <title>Hello Magento Testimonial</title>
                                    </hm_testimonial>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>      
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <testimonial>
                <file>testimonial.xml</file>
            </testimonial>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>   
<global>
    <models>
        <testimonial>
            <class>Hm_Testimonial_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>testimonial_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </testimonial>
        <testimonial_mysql4>
            <class>Hm_Testimonial_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <testimonial>
                    <table>testimonial</table>
                </testimonial>
                <testimonial_store>
                    <table>testimonial_store</table>
                </testimonial_store>                    
            </entities>
        </testimonial_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <testimonial_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Hm_Testimonial</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </testimonial_setup>
        <testimonial_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </testimonial_write>
        <testimonial_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </testimonial_read>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <testimonial>
            <class>Hm_Testimonial_Block</class>
        </testimonial>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <testimonial>
            <class>Hm_Testimonial_Helper</class>
        </testimonial>
    </helpers>
    <template>
        <email>
            <testimonial_email_email_template translate="label" module="contacts">
                <label>Testimonial Email</label>
                <file>testimonial_email.html</file>
                <type>text</type>
            </testimonial_email_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
    <events>
        <controller_front_init_before>
                <observers>
                    <testimonial>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Hm_Testimonial_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkLicense</method>
                    </testimonial>
                </observers>
        </controller_front_init_before>    
    </events>
</global>
<default>
    <hm_testimonial>
        <general>
            <enable>0</enable>
            <maxword>30</maxword>
            <delay>4000</delay>
            <width>160</width>
            <height>160</height>
            <slider>fadeZoom</slider>
            <heightslide>400</heightslide>
            <allow_media>1</allow_media>
            <allow_media_popup>1</allow_media_popup>
            <total>5</total>
            <maxfilesize>0</maxfilesize>
        </general>
        <email>
            <template_email>testimonial_email_email_template</template_email>
        </email>            
    </hm_testimonial>
</default>
```

How can I arrange installation  of 2 plugins?

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna take quite a few code changes, and most probably it would be easier to merge in any function missing from one of them, from the code in the other one.

You could of course try to change all the `<testimonial>` to `<hm_testimonial>` in the second XML, but that would also require that you change each PHP file in that module to use the corresponding `getModel('hm_testimonial/model')`, `Mage::helper('hm_testimonial')` and so on in probably every place you see "testimonial" mentioned adding "hm_" to the start.

At least it doesn't look like they are overriding any core classes, that would have made it much trickier.